# Sum of certain binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

$$\sum_{k=0}^{m} \frac{(q+k)!}{k!q!}$$

I do not know how to even start this problem. Any general tips on these types of problems will also be welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Each term is just $\dbinom{q+k}{k} = \dbinom{q+k}q$. Then just hockey stick identity.

Comment: I've never heard of any hockey stick identity. Is that slang for something more familiar like Pascal's identity?

Comment: Yes, a slang among us school boys :P .

Comment: Lol, that's actually kinda clever. I had to look it up, but I get it now. This helped http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Combinatorial_identity#Hockey-Stick_Identity

Answer (score 0):

Partial sums along diagonals in Pascal's Triangle are simply entries in the next diagonal. I can see how someone might call that a hockey stick, the shape fits. One example is the cumulative number of gifts on day $n$ in The Twelve Days of Christmas song. A little care is needed as far as what $n$ needs to be in terms of your $m.$ See for yourself:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account Will Jagy's nice remark, you can  establish that $$\sum_{k=0}^{m} \frac{(q+k)!}{k!q!}=\frac{ (m+q+1)!}{m! (q+1)!  }$$